# Unresolved reference: JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How to fix the following error?

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    ...
}
```

**Android Studio --> File --> Project Structure --> Modules --> *Unresolved reference: JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8***

[image]

Comment: Are there other options in the dropdown? Also, do you have JDK 8 or later installed?

Comment: @TheWanderer I found workaround, see below

Comment: Anyone reported this issue on issuetracker.google.com ?

Answer (score 13):

I added to the `buildscript` section of the root `build.gradle` the `ext.java_version` variable

```
buildscript {
    ...
    ext.java_version = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    ...
}
```

and changed in the module's `build.gradle` `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` to `java_version`

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility java_version
        targetCompatibility java_version
    }
    ...
}
```

Now it's all work fine.

[image]

Comment: I know it's been awhile since this post... I have the Giraffe version of AndroidStudio... I find a "buildTypes" in build.gradle, but not a "buildScript"